# Grouping a list of list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have these tables

```
public class TaskDetails
{
    public string EmployeeName {get; set;}
    public decimal EmployeeHours {get; set;}
}
public class Tasks
{
    public string TaskName {get; set;}
    public List<TaskDetails> TaskList {get; set;}
}
```

I have a function that returns a `List<Tasks>`. What I would need is to create a new List that groups the `EmployeeName`s and **SUM** the `EmployeeHours` *irrespective* of the `TaskName`. That is, I need to fetch TotalHours of each Employees. How to get that?

P.S: And to what have I done so far. I have stared at the code for a long time. Tried Rubber Duck Problem solving to no avail. I can do get the results using a `foreach` and placing it to a `Dictionary<string, decimal>`. That logic will be to check if key does not exist, add a new key and assign the value and if the key exists add the decimal value to the original value. But I feel its too much here. I feel there is a ForEach - GroupBy - Sum combination which I am missing.

Any pointers on how to do it will be very helpful for me.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. I get the error `'Tasks': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type`. You can't have a `Tasks` property on the `Tasks` class.

Comment: sorry, i was abstracting the issue and overlooked the typo. corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var results = tasks.SelectMany(x => x.Tasks)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName)
                   .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Sum(x => x.EmployeeHours));
```

Gives you `Dictionary<string, decimal>`.

To get a list just replace `ToDictionary` with `Select`/`ToList` chain:

```
var results = tasks.SelectMany(x => x.Tasks)
                   .GroupBy(x => x.EmployeeName)
                   .Select(g => new {
                       EmployeeName = g.Key,
                       Sum = g.Sum(x => x.EmployeeHours)
                   }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

a `SelectMany` would help, I think.

It will "flatten" the Lists of `TaskDetail` of all your `Task` elements into a single `IEnumerable<TaskDetail>`

```
var result = listOfTasks.SelectMany(x => x.Tasks)
             .GroupBy(m => m.EmployeeName)
             .Select(m => new {
                empName = m.Key,
                hours = m.Sum(x => x.EmployeeHours)
             });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var emplWithHours = allTasks
    .SelectMany(t => t.Tasks)
    .GroupBy(empl => empl.EmployeeName)
    .Select(empl => new
    {
        EmployeeName = empl.Key,
        TotalHours = empl.Sum(hour => hour.EmployeeHours)
    }).ToDictionary(i => i.EmployeeName, i => i.TotalHours);
```

Also, when both your class name and field name is `Tasks`, it gives a compile-time error:

```
Error   1   'Tasks': member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type
```

I would have named your class `Task` since it represents a single task.

Comment: sorry, i was abstracting the issue and overlooked the typo. corrected.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
var query =
(
    from t in tasks
    from td in t.TaskList
    group td.EmployeeHours by td.EmployeeName into ghs
    select new
    {
        EmployeeName = ghs.Key,
        EmployeeHours = ghs.Sum(),
    }
).ToDictionary(x => x.EmployeeName, x => x.EmployeeHours);
```

I slightly more succinct query would be this:

```
var query =
(
    from t in tasks
    from td in t.TaskList
    group td.EmployeeHours by td.EmployeeName
).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Sum());
```

There are pros and cons to each. I think the first is more explicit, but the second a little neater.